# Use 3D array with sigmoid(x) function

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Can I send 3d array content three channels as input for keras.activations.sigmoid(x)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, activation functions are applied per-component individually, the only exception is the softmax function, which takes a vector and returns a vector, and cannot be applied per-component.